# Show that injective immersion of a compact manifold is an embedding

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

I need to show that injective immersion of a compact manifold is an embedding.

Here is what I think - By definition, an embedding is an immersion which is **proper** and **injective**. So consider a map $F : M \rightarrow N$ s.t. $F$ is an injective immersion.  Suppose $M$ is a compact manifold. ($N$ is also a manifold). Now by default I am done with the injective part of the function as I am defining my function to be injective. Hence I am left with the **proper** part. Then by using the property  of compact manifold which says that *any continuous real-valued function is bounded on a compact manifold* , I can say that $F$ is a bounded map. But I am unable to show that it is also a closed map.

Am I right in my above reasoning (proof) or is/are there some flaws? If not then can someone please tell me how to show that $F$ is closed?

Comment: Hint: The continuous image of a compact space is...

Comment: compact.. ok got it.. I forgot this property! And is there anything wrong with my rest of the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on my comment, you'll need to apply the theorem that the continuous image of a compact space is compact.

But, the problem is missing a hypothesis: you'll need to assume that the range is Hausdorff, so that you can apply the theorem that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have mentioned that $N$ is also a manifold. That will automatically make it Hausdorff.. I have edited my question!