# Is the subset of symmetric $ 3\times 3 $ matrices with given eigenvalues a manifold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

For $ \mu_1>\mu_2>\mu_3 $ are three real numbers. Consider th set
$$
S(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)=\{A\in M(3,\mathbb{R}):,A^T=A,\,\,\lambda_1(A)=\mu_1,\lambda_2(A)=\mu_2,\lambda_3(A)=\mu_3\},
$$
where $ \lambda_1(A)>\lambda_2(A)>\lambda_3(A) $ are eigenvalues of $ A $ and $ M(3,\mathbb{R}) $ denotes the sets of $ 3\times 3 $ matrices. Then the questions is that if $ S(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3) $ is a manifold.

Here is my try, define
$$
f:\{A\in M(3,\mathbb{R}):A^T=A\}\to\mathbb{R}^3\quad(f(A)=(\lambda_1(A),\lambda_2(A),\lambda_3(A))).
$$
I want to show that for any $ \mu_1>\mu_2>\mu_3 $ the point $ (\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3) $ is a regular point of $ f $ and then $ S(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3) $ is a manifold. However I cannot deal with the derivatives of $ f $. Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: It is $\{A^T \mathrm{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3) A\mid A \in O_3(\Bbb R)\}$

Comment: Note that $f$ is not well-defined: what would be its value on $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @Didier I define $ f $ on symmetric matrices.

Comment: @Didier So how to show that $ \{Q^T\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)Q:Q\in O_3(\mathbb{R})\} $ is a manifold?

Comment: Right, sorry about that, then $f$ is well-defined if you fix a way to distinguish the eigenvalues (for instance, sort them in increasing order). In that case, you can continue your proof: this becomes a statement about monic polynomials (here, the characteristic polynomial) with distinct roots, and an appropriate use of the implicit function theorem will do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer expands on your idea, although is not the simplest way to prove the statement.
We consider the general dimension $n$.
Let us first show the following general statement:

> Let $M \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ be a real matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues.
> Then there exist a neighbourhood $U \subset M_n(\Bbb R)$ of $M$ and a smooth map $\Lambda \colon U \to \Bbb R^n$ such that for every $M' \in U$, $M'$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues given by $\Lambda(M')$.

*Proof.*
Let $V = \{(t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in \Bbb R^n \mid t_1 < \ldots < t_n \}$, which is open.
Consider the map
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
F \colon & M_n(\Bbb R) \times V & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R^n \\
& (M,t_1,\ldots,t_n) & \longmapsto & \left(P_M(t_1),\ldots, P_M(t_n) \right)
\label{eq:star} \tag{$\star$}
\end{array}
$$
where $P_M(X) = \det(M-XI_n)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M$.
Notice that $F$ polynomial in all its entries, so that $F$ is smooth.
Moreover, the differential of $F$ in the second factor at $(M_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
D_2F_{(M_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)} \colon & \Bbb R^n & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R^n \\
& (t_1,\ldots,t_n) & \longmapsto & (P'_{M_0}(\lambda_1)t_1,\ldots,P'_{M_0}(\lambda_n)t_n).
\end{array}
$$
Assume that $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) \in V$ is the spectrum of $M_0$, that is to say that $F(M_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = 0$.
Then the eigenvalues of $M_0$ are simple, and $P'_{M_0}(\lambda_j) \neq 0$ for all $j$.
It follows that $D_2F_{(M_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)}\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is an isomorphism.
By the implicit function Theorem, there exists an open neighbourhood $U_0 \subset M_n(\Bbb R)$ of $M_0$, an open neighbourhood $V_0 \subset V$ of $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, and a smooth function $\Lambda \colon U_0 \to V_0$ such that
$$
\forall (M,t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in U_0\times V_0,\quad F(M,t_1,\ldots,t_n) = 0 \iff (t_1,\ldots,t_n) = \Lambda(M).
$$
This proves the statement. $\blacksquare$

Now, for your concern, consider $M$ symmetric with distinct eigenvalues.
From the preceding study, the map $f$ you are considering is locally given by
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
f \colon & U\cap S_n(\Bbb R) & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R^n \\
& M & \longmapsto & \Lambda(M),
\end{array}
$$
where $U$ and $\Lambda \colon U \to \Bbb R^n$ are given by the above result.
The differential of $f$ at $M$ is then
$$
df_M \colon H \in S_n(\Bbb R)  \longmapsto df_M(H) = d\Lambda_M(H) \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
We thus need to compute the differential of the map $\Lambda \colon U\to \Bbb R^n$.
Notice that the map
$$
M \in U \mapsto F(M,\Lambda(M)) \in \Bbb R^n
$$
identically vanishes, where $F$ is defined by \eqref{eq:star}.
Differentiating, this yields
$$
\forall M \in U, \quad
D_1F_{(M,\Lambda(M))} + D_2F_{(M,\Lambda(M))} \circ d\Lambda_M = 0,
$$
and since $D_2F_{(M,\Lambda(M))}$ is invertible, we obtain the following expression for $d\Lambda_M$:
$$
\forall M \in U,\forall H \in M_n(\Bbb R),\quad
d\Lambda_M(H) = - (D_2F_{(M,\Lambda(M))})^{-1}\circ D_1F_{(M,\Lambda(M))}(H).
$$
Since $D_2F_{(M,\Lambda(M))}$ is an isomorphism, to show that $f \colon S_n(\Bbb R)\cap U \to \Bbb R^n$ is a submersion at $M$, one only needs to show that $D_1F_{(M,\Lambda(M))} \colon S_n(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R^n$ is surjective.
By [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), we have
$$
\newcommand{\adj}{\mathrm{adj}} \newcommand{\trace}{\mathrm{trace}}
D_1F_{(M,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)}(H) =
(\trace(\adj(M-\lambda_1I_n)H),\ldots,\trace(\adj(M-\lambda_n I_n)H).
$$
This last expression is a bit annoying, but here is a trick to overcome this difficulty.
Note that there exists $O\in O_n(\Bbb R)$ such that
$$
\newcommand{\diag}{\mathrm{diag}}
O^{-1}MO = \diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n),
$$
and that since $f(M) = f(O^{-1}MO)$, one has
$$
df_M(H) = df_{O^{-1}MO}(O^{-1}HO).
$$
Since $H\in S_n(\Bbb R) \mapsto O^{-1}HO \in S_n(\Bbb R)$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show the surjectivity of $df_M$ for $M = \diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_1 < \cdots <\lambda_n$.
But then, one has
$$
\adj(\diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) - \lambda_jI_n)
= \adj(\diag(\lambda_1-\lambda_j,\ldots, \lambda_n-\lambda_j))
= \diag(0,\ldots, 0,\alpha_j, 0,\ldots,0) 
$$
with $\alpha_j = \prod_{i\neq j}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j) \neq 0$.
Choose $H' = \diag(\frac{t_1}{\alpha_1},\ldots,\frac{t_n}{\alpha_n})$, and notice that
$$
df_{\diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)}(H') = (t_1,\ldots,t_n).
$$
The result now follows.

Comment: To use the results of regular point, one need to show that $ D_1F_{(M,\Lambda(M))} $ is a surjective map, here I do not know how to show it, which is the obstacle in my proof.

Comment: @LuisYankaAnnalisc I added an expression for $D_1F$. Notice that by assumption, $M - \lambda_j I_n$ has rank $n-1$ (this will be helpful to show the surjectivity)

Comment: May the downvoter explain their vote?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This second answer gives a shorter proof, more algebraic, which does not expand on your ideas.
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$

We will use the following fact twice, whose proof is given by elementary computations:

> If $D$ is a diagonal matrix with distinct entries, then its commutator $\mathcal{C}(D)$ is precisely the set of diagonal matrices.

Let $D = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &\lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}$ with $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3$.
Consider the action $\O_3(\Bbb R) \curvearrowright S_3(\Bbb R)$ given by $O\cdot M = OMO^T$.
The spectral Theorem yields that $S(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ is exactly the orbit $S(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) = \mathrm{Orb}(D)$.

Let $g\colon \O_3(\Bbb R) \to S_3(\Bbb R)$ be given by $g(O) = O\cdot D$, which is smooth.
Notice that $g$ is equivariant:
$$
\forall O_1,O_2 \in \O_3(\Bbb R), \quad
g(O_1O_2) = O_1\cdot g(O_2).
$$
This implies that if $O\in \O_3(\Bbb R)$ and $H \in T_O \O_3(\Bbb R)$ then
$$
dg_O(H)
= O(dg_{I_3}(O^TH)) O^T,
$$
and $g$ has constant rank, equal to its rank at $I_3$.
Notice that $T_{I_3}\O_3(\Bbb R) = A_3(\Bbb R)$ is the space of antisymmetric matrices, so that we have
$$
dg_{I_3} \colon H \in A_3(\Bbb R) \longmapsto DH - HD \in S_3(\Bbb R).
$$
Hence, $\ker dg_{I_3} = A_3(\Bbb R) \cap \mathcal{C}(D)$, where $\mathcal{C}(D)$ is the set of matrices that commute with $D$, which are the diagonal matrices.
Since the only antisymmetric diagonal matrix is the zero matrix, one obtains that $\ker dg_{I_3} = \{0\}$.
It follows that $g$ is and immersion.

As a consequence, if $\mathrm{Stab}(D) = g^{-1}(D)$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $D$, then $g$ induces a smooth injective immersion
$$
\bar{g} \colon \O_3(\Bbb R) / \mathrm{Stab}(D) \to S_3(\Bbb R).
$$
We compute $\mathrm{Stab}(D)$:
\begin{align}
g(O) = D
\iff OD = DO 
\iff O \in \mathcal{C}(D)\cap \O_3(\Bbb R) 
\iff O =
\begin{pmatrix}
\pm 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \pm 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \pm 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, $\mathrm{Stab}(D)$ is discrete, and $\O_3(\Bbb R) / \mathrm{Stab}(D)$ has dimension $\dim \O_3(\Bbb R) = 3$.
Since $\O_3(\Bbb R)$ is compact, $\O_3(\Bbb R)/\mathrm{Stab}(D)$ is also a compact manifold.
Hence, $\bar{g} \colon \O_3(\Bbb R)/\mathrm{Stab}(D) \to S_3(\Bbb R)$ is a smooth injective immersion from a compact manifold, and [is thus an embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952990/show-that-injective-immersion-of-a-compact-manifold-is-an-embedding).
It follows that its image $S(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$ is a submanifold of $S_3(\Bbb R)$ of dimension $\dim\O_3(\Bbb R) = 3$.